# List is not re-rendering the child components

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am using `react-virtualized` to window my dropdown list options.
The problem is that these options are not rendering its content.

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
      defaultHeight: 24,
      fixedWidth: true,
    });

    this.rowRenderer = this.rowRenderer.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listComponent.recomputeRowHeights();
    this.listComponent.forceUpdateGrid();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.cache.clearAll();
    this.listComponent.recomputeRowHeights();
    this.listComponent.forceUpdateGrid();
  }

  rowRenderer = ({ index, style, key, option, measure }) => {
    const { description, checked, label, vdsID: id } = option;
    return (
      <div style={style} key={key}>
        <DropdownOptionMolecule
          description={description}
          checked={checked}
          label={label}
          key={index}
          onChange={this.onOptionChange}
          id={id}
          type={this.type}
          onLoad={measure}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };

  measureRowRenderer = (opt) => ({ key, index, style, parent }) => {
    const { options } = this.props;
    const option = options[index];

    return (
      <CellMeasurer cache={this.cache} columnIndex={0} key={key} rowIndex={index} parent={parent}>
        {(m) => this.rowRenderer({ ...m, index, option, key, style })}
      </CellMeasurer>
    );
  };

render() {
return (
<div style={{ width: '200px', height: '500px' }}>
          <AutoSizer>
            {({ width, hegiht }) => (
              <List
                width={200}
                height={400}
                rowCount={options.length}
                rowHeight={this.cache.rowHeight}
                rowRenderer={this.measureRowRenderer(options)}
                data={options}
                deferredMeasurementCache={this.cache}
                ref={(listComponent) => (this.listComponent = listComponent)}
              />
            )}
          </AutoSizer>
        </div>
)};
```

And this is the `DropdownOptionMolecule`'s content.

```
<dropdown-option-molecule onClick={handleOptionClick}>
  {label}
  {type === DropdownTypes.MULTI && (
    <TickboxTextMolecule description={description} checked={checked} id={id} onChange={onChange}>
      {label}
    </TickboxTextMolecule>
  )}
  {type === DropdownTypes.SINGLE && (
    <RadioboxTextMolecule
      label={label}
      description={description}
      checked={checked}
      id={id}
      onChange={onChange}
      type={radioBoxTypes.SELECT}
    />
  )}
</dropdown-option-molecule>
```

All options are rendered inside react-virtualized but the problem is that it's only rendering the `label` and no other components inside it.

`TickboxTextMolecule` and `RadioboxTextMolecule` are not rendering at all.

How can I solve this problem?